# Pig CROSS versus replicated JOIN

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I need to do a non-equijoin in Pig. The first thing I want to try is CROSS + filter:

```
    together = CROSS A, B;
    filtered = FILTER together BY (JOIN PREDICATE);
```

However, one of the relations is definitely small enough to fit in memory. This makes me wonder how CROSS is actually implemented in Pig. Can it do a 'replicated' CROSS?

If not, I could do something like this:

```
    small = FOREACH small GENERATE *, 1 AS key:int;
    large = FOREACH large GENERATE *, 1 AS key:int;
    together = JOIN large BY key, small BY key USING 'replicated';
    filtered = FILTER together BY (JOIN PREDICATE);
```

Would the second approach see any performance gain?

Answer (score 2):

So, for the large relation with 2M records and the small relation with 500K records, the replicated join was MUCH faster.

However, both were too slow and I ended up implementing a UDF that allowed a normal replicated join at the cost of increasing the size of the large relation by a bit.

For cases where this isn't possible, it seems like the replicated join with the phony key is the way to go.

Comment: The replicated join will definitely be much faster because it's done in the map and the cross join triggers a reduce. I'm not sure how you could do a join with a UDF because you couldn't guarantee that all your join keys would be in the same map task for both relations.

Answer (score 1):

Thats a good point! Good question indeed.

Under the hood CROSS is translated to GFCross and COGROUP as explained [here](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=RG-v6qUktSYC&lpg=PA68&ots=tQK-ETSGjx&dq=pig%20gfcross&pg=PA68&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=pig%20gfcross&f=true). 
Please note that Pig's philosophy says 'Pig is a domestic animal' and thus does not do much for optimizing the performance. Instead, user should change the behavior to get the best performance for their data.

I think (am not 100% sure) your alternate solution implementing your own CROSS using JOIN on dummy column should give you better performance.

Anyways, you can have couple of test runs to compare the performance and have your results on your own!

Comment: thanks! I'll give it a shot tomorrow. nice to know that this isn't obvious